# How to use GVR pools and PoolManager

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, google-vr

I want to use several [GameObject pools](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/blob/27666a66e54427758c8a6aaa6701084ffd456cff/Assets/GoogleVR/Demos/Scripts/ScrollingUIDemo/Pooling/GameObjectPool.cs) so I need the pool [manager](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/blob/27666a66e54427758c8a6aaa6701084ffd456cff/Assets/GoogleVR/Demos/Scripts/ScrollingUIDemo/Pooling/ObjectPoolManager.cs) but I don't understand how to use it and I couldn't find any docs.

How am I supposed to define a new pool that uses a GameObject called "enemy" for example?

Am I supposed to inherit a new concrete class from GameObjectPool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pool manager has static instance that is set on Awake. You should attach ObjectPoolManager script to some GameObject in the scene.

[image]

Then you can make pools for different GameObjects:

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject enemyPrefab;
public GameObject itemPrefab;
public GameObject characterPrefab;

const int enemyCount = 100;
const int itemCount = 100;

private GameObjectPool EnemyPool {
    get {
        GameObjectPool pool = ObjectPoolManager.Instance.GetPool<GameObjectPool> (enemyPrefab.name);
        if (pool == null) {
            pool = new GameObjectPool(enemyPrefab, enemyCount);
            ObjectPoolManager.Instance.AddPool(enemyPrefab.name, pool);
        }
        return pool;
    }
}

private GameObjectPool ItemPool {
    get {
        GameObjectPool pool = ObjectPoolManager.Instance.GetPool<GameObjectPool> (itemPrefab.name);
        if (pool == null) {
            pool = new GameObjectPool(itemPrefab, itemCount);
            ObjectPoolManager.Instance.AddPool(itemPrefab.name, pool);
        }
        return pool;
    }
}


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    StartCoroutine(SpawnEnemy (1f));
}


IEnumerator SpawnEnemy(float t) {
    for (int i = 0; i < enemyCount; ++i) {
        GameObject newEnemy = EnemyPool.Borrow ();
        newEnemy.transform.position = Random.insideUnitSphere;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (t);
    }
}


}
```